How do I play an MP3 file from Polaris NB IoT board to MP3Click with VS1053 decoding chip?
I have a Polaris NB IoT board on which I have an SD card that contains an MP3 file. I am trying to play said file on an MP3Click using SPI communication. I am using Python to code my board. I am able to write to the MP3 Click using this function and can read the data I send from a similar function.
def write_register(register, value):
    
    high_byte = (value >> 8) & 0xFF
    
    spi.select()
    low_byte = value & 0xFF
    spi.write(bytearray([SCI_WRITE, register, high_byte, low_byte]))
    spi.unselect() 

However when I try to write my byte data from my MP3 file there is no sound being played. Why might this be? I am certain the MP3 file has data.

DREQ_PIN = D0  # Data request pin
pinMode(DREQ_PIN,INPUT_PULLUP)
RESET_PIN = D1  # Reset pin

SCI_MODE = 0x00
SCI_VOL = 0x0B
SCI_STATUS = 0x01
SCI_WRAM = 0x06
SCI_WRAMADDR = 0x07
SCI_READ = 0x03
SCI_WRITE = 0x02
SM_STREAM = 0x08

spi = spi.Spi(D2, clock=1000000, bits=spi.SPI_8_BITS, mode=spi.SPI_MODE_LOW_FIRST)

def send_mp3_data(register, data):
    while digitalRead(DREQ_PIN) == LOW:
        sleep(100)  # Wait until DREQ is high
    spi.select()
    spi.write(data)
    spi.unselect()

def play_mp3(filename):
    mp3_file = os.open(filename, 'rb+')
    while True:
        # Wait for DREQ to go high
        while digitalRead(DREQ_PIN) == LOW:
            soft_reset_vs1053()
            sleep(10)
        
        data = mp3_file.read(32)
        if not data:
            print("EOF")
            break  # End of file
        # Send the data chunk to VS1053B
        send_mp3_data(SCI_WRITE,data)
    print("Playback finished")

I have tried plugging both a wired in ear headset into the headphone jack and an amplifier connected to a speaker. The in ear headset makes no noise at all while the speaker is constantly buzzing loudly, also while no data is being sent. I have attached an image of my board layout. The MP3 Click is inserted into the micro bus of the board. 

Don’t you need to set some kind of mode using SCI commands before you send data? Do you see DREQ go high/low? Have tou tried the SCI status command? Is SPI actually possible on D2? Shouldn’t you specify the SPI clock pin as well? Isn’t there a dedicated SDK?

which part of your post is about an IoT problem?

@jsotola the board used is a “Polaris NB IoT board” :-)

@jsotola it was a joke

@jcaron my apologies, I was not paying attention to who posted the comment... I thought that the OP posted it

@jcaron It is my understanding of the datasheet https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/vs1053.pdf on page 39 that it is set to SDINEW by default and this would be the correct state, but I have also tried setting the mode to stream with no different result.
I read DREQ as HIGH and have not seen it go low yet.
The SCI status command returns 0.
I am not sure if it is, it felt like the natural pin since the CS pin of the decoder is plugged into this pin when inserted into the micro bus.
I am not sure what an SPI clock pin is?

@jsotola It is my understanding that the communication between the board and the MP3Click is considered IoT. Is this not correct?

Ah, sorry, a very quick glance through the datasheet had made me think there were two separate SPI interfaces, when it’s actually a single interface with two different CS pins. But I think you got the pin wrong: shouldn’t you be using DCS (D15) to send data rather than CS (D2) which is used for commands?

@jcaron That might be correct, I believe it should be pin 7 though? I seem to be unable to force the DREQ pin low even in a loop spamming commands to it, perhaps I am handling the DREQ incorrectly? It is initially LOW on startup but is then never pulled LOW even when clearly being overloaded. Also, the SCI_STATUS reads to 72 or 0x48

Yes, sorry, it’s pin 15 on the module but that’s D7.

@LukasEliassen IoT includes communication to a network of some kind ... it does not include communication to a local peripheral, such as an MP3 module ... if that was the case, then almost every project in existence would be labeled as IoT ... if you have problems with communication to a server or to another Polaris board, then your question belongs here, otherwise it does not
